# how to disable parent view's user interaction - iPad

Tags: ipad

I have added a sub view on the screen. Now I want to disable the parent view's user interation. But when i do this using -

```
GenreShelfViewController *gsvc = (GenreShelfViewController *) parent;
[gsvc.view setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
[gsvc release];
```

(I am doing this in subview's viewDidLoad method)

Sub view also freezes up and not responding to interations.

Any other idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this if you make the subview the same size as your parent's view,
set the background color to "clearColor",
photoshop a dialog background,
insert a UIImage to represent the dialog background you just created,
and place your dialog controls on top of the UIImage control.

Since the child view will technically consume the entire screen, it will appear the controls behind the child are "frozen".

If its a tableview, also disable the scrolling.